# Can't apply unified diff patch on Solaris

Tags: diff, solaris, patch, unified-diff

For example, if I have two files:

file1:

```
This is file 1
```

and file2:

```
This is file 2
```

and create patch with the following command:

```
diff -u file1 file2 > files.patch
```

result is:

```
--- file1       Fri Aug 13 17:53:28 2010
+++ file2       Fri Aug 13 17:53:38 2010
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-This is file 1
+This is file 2
```

Then if I try to apply this patch on Solaris with patch command:

```
patch -u -i files.patch
```

it hangs on:

```
 Looks like a unified context diff.
File to patch:
```

**1. Is there a way to use Solaris *native patch command* with unified diffs?**

**2. Which diff format is considered most portable if it's not possible to apply unified format?**

**Update:**
I've found answer on the first part of my question. Seems that `patch` on Solaris hangs if the second file (file2 in this case) exists in the same folder as the first one (file1). For example, the following quite common diff:

```
--- a/src/file.src       Sat Aug 14 23:07:29 2010
+++ b/src/file.src       Sat Aug 14 23:07:37 2010
@@ -1,2 +1,1 @@
-1
-
+2
```

will not work with quite common patch command:

```
patch -p1 -u -d a < file.patch
```

while the following diff (**note second file is renamed**):

```
--- a/src/file.src       Sat Aug 14 23:07:29 2010
+++ b/src/file_new.src       Sat Aug 14 23:07:37 2010
@@ -1,2 +1,1 @@
-1
-
+2
```

will work perfectly.

For the second part of my question see accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Unix v2 and v3 both support context diffs but not unified diffs, so for better portability you should use context diffs (`-c` option to `diff` and `patch`).

On older Solaris releases (pre-10, I think), you need to make sure that `/usr/xpg4/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`, otherwise you may get compatibility versions of some utilities instead of standard ones.

Comment: Thank you, Gilles for explanations. I'll consider using context diffs. As far as I understand, you can't write in context diff patch information about source file to change. Am I right? It's not very convenient ... Anyway, I still can't understand why I failed to run patch -u with diff produced by diff -u.

Comment: @Shcheklein: What do you mean by “patch information about source file to change”? Context diffs do include file names. POSIX requires `diff -cr` to be supported, so this has to work. By the way, does `patch -p0` make a difference?

Comment: Yes, context diffs include enough information. However, the problem with Solaris's `patch` was the different (see update of the question). `-p0` doesn't make any difference. Seems that `patch` on Solaris doesn't like when both names in hunk are same or both files exist.

Answer (score 6):

On Solaris `/usr/bin/patch` is an old version required to comply with some ancient standards.
A modern version of GNU patch is provided as `/usr/bin/gpatch` on Solaris 8 and later.

Comment: I know. It's possible that gpatch is not installed by default and it's not very good when compilation of your product failed because there is no gpatch.

Answer (score 2):

```
diff -cr old.new new.txt > patch.txt

gpatch -p0 < patch.txt
```

Works perfectly for me (using gpatch)